# My control doesn't seem to want to align at all

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, alignment

I have been working on the XAML of my Windows Phone application, and again, I'm facing another moment where I want to bang my head against a wall. It seems as if a control simply does not want to align anywhere, no difference if I specify the HorizontalAlignment to the left, right, stretch, etc. There's probably something obvious that I didn't notice that's preventing my controls from aligning properly, however, I cannot figure it out! Here is a code sample, and if you paste it into a Windows Phone app page, you'll see what I mean:

```
<c4fToolkit:ChatBubble HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="320" ChatBubbleDirection="{Binding Direction}" >
    <StackPanel Width="310">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" TextAlignment="Right" />
    </StackPanel>
</c4fToolkit:ChatBubble>
```

(The ChatBubble control is from the Coding4Fun Toolkit)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the role of the alignment. Putting the alignment on the chatbubble will align the chatbubble as a whole, not the contained controls. Imagine you have a button, and set its alignment to the right: you'll expect the button to be displayed to the right, but you would want the label inside of the button to be still centered.

Comment: Please post the whole visual tree of the page, the alignment of the bubble might be affected by one of its ancestors.